# Pass by reference issue using a delegate inside a loop

Tags: c#, delegates, pass-by-reference

I have the following code which creates and returns a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`

```
private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();

private static Dictionary<int, List<string>> GenerateValues(string entityType, int rows)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

    var baseValues = new List<string> { "99 Hellesdon Road","Home","Norfolk","NR6 5EG","Norwich" };

    Action<int> rowLoop = null;

    switch (entityType)
    {
        case "Employer":
            rowLoop = (row) =>
            {
                var employer = new List<string>
                {
                    $"Employer {rnd.Next(10000, 99999)}",
                    $"{rnd.Next(100000000, 999999999)}",
                    "TRUE"
                };

                var rowValue = baseValues;
                rowValue.AddRange(employer);
                values.Add(row, rowValue);
            };
            break;
        case "AssessmentCentre":
            rowLoop = (row) =>
            {
                var rowValue = baseValues;
                rowValue.Add($"Assessment Centre {rnd.Next(10000, 99999)}");
                values.Add(row, rowValue);
            };
            break;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        rowLoop(i);
    }

    return values;
}
```

And then to call it with...

```
var spreadsheetValues = GenerateValues("Employer", 5);
```

Then intention for the code is to have some base values stored in a `List<string>`, then depending on what `entityType` is passed into the method, add some additional values to those base values. Then loop round a certain number of rows to create the `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`, where `int` is the row number.

The issue I'm having is that `baseValues` is being updated during each iteration of my for loop. I didn't expect this when using `var rowValue = baseValues;`

This is a debug screenshot of the last item in the collection....

[image]

I am expecting each `List<string>` in `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` to contain 8 items, but instead it is growing with each iteration.

Why is this occurring and how might I correct it?

Comment: Instead of reusing the same `baseValue` again and again adding more items there every iteration - you can do something like `employer.InsertRange(0, baseValues);values.Add(row, employer);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are already on track with the solution to your problem but here is a way to solve it.

Where you write

```
var rowValue = baseValues;
```

you are really just making "rowValue" a pointer to "baseValues". To make a copy, you could do something like this:

```
var rowValue = baseValues.ToList();
```